# Merge dicts inside lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists with same length:

```
[{'a':1, 'b':105}, {'a':2, 'b':99}]
[20, 25]
```

How can I add a key for second list to make:

```
[{'c':20}, {'c':25}]
```

And then to merge these two lists to get:

```
[{'a':1, 'b':105, 'c':20}, {'a':2, 'b':99, 'c':25}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
d, d2 = [{'a':1, 'b':105}, {'a':2, 'b':99}], [20, 25]
new_d = [{**a, 'c':b} for a, b in zip(d, d2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 105, 'c': 20}, {'a': 2, 'b': 99, 'c': 25}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to update the dicts in the list with a new key, you can modify them in-place with a loop after pairing the list of dicts and the list of values with `zip`:

```
lst = [{'a':1, 'b':105}, {'a':2, 'b':99}]
vals = [20, 25]
for d, val in zip(lst, vals):
    d['c'] = val
```

`lst` would become:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 105, 'c': 20}, {'a': 2, 'b': 99, 'c': 25}]
```